# How to install gnome-app-install?

Tags: 10.10, software-center, package-management

The software centre is slow and annoying (packages from additional repositories don't show up sometimes etc.), so I want the old *Add/remove software* application back.
I've found out that the package is called `gnome-app-install`. The problem is that it just won't let me install it.

When I run `sudo apt-get install gnome-app-install` it tells me this:

```
Warning, 'software-center' will be selected in stead of 'gnome-app-install'
software-center is already the latest version.
```

How do I get the old *Add/remove software* application back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `gnome-app-install` isn't a real package, but a [virtual package](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.html#s-virtual):

```
$ apt-cache show gnome-app-install
N: Can't select versions from package 'gnome-app-install' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

that is provided by `software-center`:

```
$ apt-cache show software-center
Package: software-center
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
...
Replaces: gnome-app-install, software-store
Provides: gnome-app-install, software-store
```

In fact, there isn't any other package that provides `gnome-app-install`:

```
$ aptitude search '?provides(gnome-app-install)'
i   software-center                 - Utility for browsing, installing, and remo
```

Hence, I'd say that there isn't any other official alternative that provides that virtual package, so I'd encourage you to report problems in the [launchpad project page](https://launchpad.net/software-center) to help them get fixed in future releases.

Anyway, if you're still unhappy with `software-center`, I suggest to give a try to `synaptic`.

Comment: Synaptic's for advanced use, so not very user-friendly. Gnome-app-install on the other hand is just as easy to use as the software centre.

Comment: Ah well, doesn't matter much. I'll just keep using `aptitude search` and `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want something like that (as I do). Give `gnome-packagekit` a try. It works in pretty much the same way. It has the checkboxes and the categories. It is fast to load and lightweight as well.